# Exception thrown when trying to disable a control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a **Ribbon CheckBox** and a **Ribbon RadioButton**. When CheckBox is checked, the RadioButton will be disable and grayed out.  This supposed to be very easy (see following code), but when the program compile, it kept giving an error:

**"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

Which I don't quite understand. Following is my code:

```
<ribbon:RibbonCheckBox Unchecked="CheckBox1_Unchecked"
                       Checked="CheckBox1_Checked" IsChecked="True"
                       Label="Foo" />

<ribbon:RibbonRadioButton x:Name="radioButton1" Label="=Santa" />

private void CheckBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    radioButton1.IsEnabled = false;  // this is where exception is thrown
}
```

Comment: Try to create a sample project as small as possible that still has this problem. Your code looks fine and shouldn't throw that exception.

Comment: sorry this is already as simple as it is - a checkbox and a radiobutton. I absolutely see no reason why it would throw me an exception. May be a bug in Ribbon Control?

Comment: In your constructor, there should be a call to `InitializeComponents`. Please verify that `radioButton1` is non-null after that call.

Comment: well, a small piece I missed - IsChecked event. If I remove it, the code compiles fine. But the problem is I will also need to initialize the CheckBox to be Checked. SO that brings another problem.

Comment: The above code also compiles fine. Don't mix compile time errors and runtime errors...

Comment: can you post your xaml.cs file.. as daniel said this may related to InitializeComponet it not your xaml.cs come may help us to give you better solution

Comment: then add it to your constructor and check for null in the event handler. It's probably that your checkbox is initialized before the radio button, so when it's checked first, your radio button is still null.

Comment: You could bind IsEnabled to IsChecked and invert the result in a converter. To do it in the checked/unchecked events, add a null check for the radiobutton since it will probably execute before the radiobutton is initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your control is loaded, the CheckBox is created first, then the RadioButton.  Likely the event is hooked up earlier than your radioButton1 is set.  You can verify this by removing the IsChecked=true from the XAML temporarily.

A couple of options here:

1. Data Binding - use the IsChecked property to automatically update your radio button without code.  You'll need to name your checkbox.

   IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox1, Mode=OneWay}"
2. Check for null in your existing code -

   if (radioButton1 != null)
   {
       radioButton1.IsEnabled = false;
   }
3. Updated your radioButton state after the Loaded event has completed.

   private bool isLoaded;

   protected override OnLoaded(...)
   {
      this.isLoaded = true;
   }

   private void CheckBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     if (this.isLoaded)
     {
       radioButton1.IsEnabled = false;  // this is where exception is thrown
     }
   }

The preferred method is generally #1.